# Looking for help on animating an image across the page

Tags: html, css

Let me preface that I am a huge noob when it comes to HTML/CSS. I am trying to get a PNG image to be animated across the page and found [this CodePen](https://codepen.io/mohaiman/pen/MQqMyo) that slightly achieves what I'm looking for. Right now, this is just animated squares that become rounded as they float up.

Can someone point me in the right direction on how to fill these squares with a PNG image? Or am I trying to do something impossible? (I've been researching this for 3 hours now)

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Exo:400,700");

* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

body {
  font-family: "Exo", sans-serif;
}

.context {
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50vh;
}

.context h1 {
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 50px;
}

.area {
  background: #4e54c8;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to left, #8f94fb, #4e54c8);
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}

.circles {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.circles li {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  list-style: none;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
  animation: animate 25s linear infinite;
  bottom: -150px;
}

.circles li:nth-child(1) {
  left: 25%;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  animation-delay: 0s;
}

.circles li:nth-child(2) {
  left: 10%;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  animation-delay: 2s;
  animation-duration: 12s;
}

.circles li:nth-child(3) {
  left: 70%;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  animation-delay: 4s;
}

.circles li:nth-child(4) {
  left: 40%;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  animation-delay: 0s;
  animation-duration: 18s;
}

.circles li:nth-child(5) {
  left: 65%;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  animation-delay: 0s;
}

.circles li:nth-child(6) {
  left: 75%;
  width: 110px;
  height: 110px;
  animation-delay: 3s;
}

.circles li:nth-child(7) {
  left: 35%;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  animation-delay: 7s;
}

.circles li:nth-child(8) {
  left: 50%;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  animation-delay: 15s;
  animation-duration: 45s;
}

.circles li:nth-child(9) {
  left: 20%;
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  animation-delay: 2s;
  animation-duration: 35s;
}

.circles li:nth-child(10) {
  left: 85%;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  animation-delay: 0s;
  animation-duration: 11s;
}

@keyframes animate {
  0% {
transform: translateY(0) rotate(0deg);
opacity: 1;
border-radius: 0;
  }

  100% {
transform: translateY(-1000px) rotate(720deg);
opacity: 0;
border-radius: 50%;
  }
}
```

```html
       

<div class="context">
  <h1>Pure Css Animated Background</h1>
</div>

<div class="area">
  <ul class="circles">
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

## Using `background-image: url('')` Property:

Using the `background-image:` property may allow you to change the background of the child elements of class circles in this case the list `<li>` elements. Here I change them all to a single image but you could set each `<li>` element individually. The `background-image:` property can be set to a `url` of the image → `background-image: url('')` within the quotation `''` you can specify the image path/url. To ensure the image does not get clipped you can add the `background-size` property and set it to `background-size: 100% 100%` to fill the entire element. If you'd like the image to not distort use `background-image: cover` and set the position by using `background-position:` such an example is `background-position: 50% 50%`.

[image: Background Image Property Image]

### Class elements to add a property to (CSS):

```
.circles li{
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    list-style: none;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
    animation: animate 25s linear infinite;
    bottom: -150px;
    background-image: url('https://picsum.photos/200'); 
    background-size: 100% 100%;
}
```

### Runnable Script Playground (HTML/CSS):

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Exo:400,700');

*{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

body{
    font-family: 'Exo', sans-serif;
}


.context {
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top:50vh;
    
}

.context h1{
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 50px;
}


.area{
    background: #4e54c8;  
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to left, #8f94fb, #4e54c8);  
    width: 100%;
    height:100vh;
    
   
}

.circles{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.circles li{
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    list-style: none;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
    animation: animate 25s linear infinite;
    bottom: -150px;
    background-image: url('https://picsum.photos/200');  
    background-size: 100% 100%;

}

.circles li:nth-child(1){
    left: 25%;
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    animation-delay: 0s;
}


.circles li:nth-child(2){
    left: 10%;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    animation-delay: 2s;
    animation-duration: 12s;
}

.circles li:nth-child(3){
    left: 70%;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    animation-delay: 4s;
}

.circles li:nth-child(4){
    left: 40%;
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    animation-delay: 0s;
    animation-duration: 18s;
}

.circles li:nth-child(5){
    left: 65%;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    animation-delay: 0s;
}

.circles li:nth-child(6){
    left: 75%;
    width: 110px;
    height: 110px;
    animation-delay: 3s;
}

.circles li:nth-child(7){
    left: 35%;
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    animation-delay: 7s;
}

.circles li:nth-child(8){
    left: 50%;
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    animation-delay: 15s;
    animation-duration: 45s;
}

.circles li:nth-child(9){
    left: 20%;
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
    animation-delay: 2s;
    animation-duration: 35s;
}

.circles li:nth-child(10){
    left: 85%;
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    animation-delay: 0s;
    animation-duration: 11s;
}



@keyframes animate {

    0%{
        transform: translateY(0) rotate(0deg);
        opacity: 1;
        border-radius: 0;
    }

    100%{
        transform: translateY(-1000px) rotate(720deg);
        opacity: 0;
        border-radius: 50%;
    }

}
```

```html
<div class="context">
        <h1>Pure Css Animated Background</h1>
    </div>


<div class="area" >
            <ul class="circles">
                    <li></li>
                    <li></li>
                    <li></li>
                    <li></li>
                    <li></li>
                    <li></li>
                    <li></li>
                    <li></li>
                    <li></li>
                    <li></li>
            </ul>
    </div >
```

Comment: I tried this at some point as well, but I'm not seeing the image actually show. Even when I run the code snippet here, it's the normal boxes with no image.

Comment: Where is your image stored locally?

Comment: I'm pulling it from my SharePoint

Comment: That's a cloud-based storage/drive right? Might not work because of permissions or other reasons.

Comment: I can throw the image somewhere else, but admittedly I'm a little confused... The image you added is EXACTLY what I'm trying to achieve, but even when I use the code you shared, I'm not seeing the image pull through to the squares.

Comment: Actually, I see it run. Hmm, which browser or environment are you using? It sometimes takes a few seconds to pull the image.

Comment: Try this to see if this work in your current browser: https://github.com/MichaelTr7/StackOverflow/tree/master/Squares%20Test. Keep in mind the image `url()` I used randomly generates an image.

Comment: I added a property to make sure the image scales properly.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a different image in each circle then you c an put the relevant image name in each of these

```
.circles li:nth-child(1){
    left: 25%;
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    animation-delay: 0s;
    background-image: url(image.png);
}
```

You mention filling each bubble so in the general setting for each setting add

.circles li {
background-size: cover;
}

If you want to be sure that the whole of an image appears in each bubble then use contain instead of cover.

Answer (score 1):

You can use just `img` instead of `li`.

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Exo:400,700");

* {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

body {
    font-family: "Exo", sans-serif;
}

.context {
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50vh;
}

.context h1 {
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 50px;
}

.area {
    background: #4e54c8;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to left, #8f94fb, #4e54c8);
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
}

.circles {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.circles img {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    list-style: none;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
    animation: animate 25s linear infinite;
    bottom: -150px;
}

.circles img:nth-child(1) {
    left: 25%;
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    animation-delay: 0s;
}

.circles img:nth-child(2) {
    left: 10%;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    animation-delay: 2s;
    animation-duration: 12s;
}

.circles img:nth-child(3) {
    left: 70%;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    animation-delay: 4s;
}

.circles img:nth-child(4) {
    left: 40%;
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    animation-delay: 0s;
    animation-duration: 18s;
}

.circles img:nth-child(5) {
    left: 65%;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    animation-delay: 0s;
}

.circles img:nth-child(6) {
    left: 75%;
    width: 110px;
    height: 110px;
    animation-delay: 3s;
}

.circles img:nth-child(7) {
    left: 35%;
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    animation-delay: 7s;
}

.circles img:nth-child(8) {
    left: 50%;
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    animation-delay: 15s;
    animation-duration: 45s;
}

.circles img:nth-child(9) {
    left: 20%;
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
    animation-delay: 2s;
    animation-duration: 35s;
}

.circles img:nth-child(10) {
    left: 85%;
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    animation-delay: 0s;
    animation-duration: 11s;
}

@keyframes animate {
    0% {
        transform: translateY(0) rotate(0deg);
        opacity: 1;
        border-radius: 0;
    }

    100% {
        transform: translateY(-1000px) rotate(720deg);
        opacity: 0;
        border-radius: 50%;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="context">
  <h1>Pure Css Animated Background</h1>
</div>

<div class="area">
  <div class="circles">
   <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300"/>
   <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300"/>
   <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300"/>
   <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300"/>
   <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300"/>
   <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300"/>
   <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300"/>
  </div>
</div>
```